# In a panel data of products (per store/week), identify products that are present in all store/week panels

Tags: loops, stata

In the data set below, store/week is a panel. I would like to show that products 4, 5, 6 are present in all the panels. Binary variable `present1` indicates it.

Similarly, I would like to recognize the presence of products in the corresponding number of occurrences. Categorical variable  present2 indicates it.

```
clear
input expbasedem price   product store  str7 l5 week present1 present2 
      1.1  5.3 1   1   Ana 1 0 
      1.1  2.5 3   1   Bob 1 0 3
      1.1  1   4   1   Brian 1 1 4
      2.1  12  5   1   Brian 1 1 4
      3.1  12  6   1   Suming 1 1 4

      12  4   2   2   Ana 1 0 2
      12  3.5 3   2   Bob 1 0 3 
      10  2   4   2   Brian 1 1 4
      25  13  5   2   Brian 1 1 4
      35  13  6   2   Suming 1 1 4

      35.3  5.3 7   1   Bob 2 0 1
      12.3  2.5 8  1   Brian 2 0 1
      10.3  1   4  1   Brian 2 1 4
      35.3  12  5   1   Bobby 2 1 4
      35.3  12  6   1   Becky 2 1 4

      23.4  4   2   2   Icarus 2 0 2
      12.4  3.5 3   2   Xerox 2 0 3
      10.4  2   4   2   Yulia 2 1 4
      35.4  13  5   2   Zebra 2 1 4
      35.4  13  6   2   Ninjago 2 1 4
end
```

I think I know how to do present2:

```
bysort product: generate order = _n
drop tag
bysort product: egen tag=max(order)
```

`present1`requires loops, I think, but I don't go far:

```
sort week store product  
egen joint1 = group (week store), label 

gen long id = _n 
su joint1, meanonly  

forval i = 1/`r(max)' { 
   su id if joint1 == `i', meanonly
   local jmin = r(min) 
   local jmax = r(max) 

...
...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your first question about `present1` as wanting an indicator that is

1 if and only if products 4, 5, 6 are all available in a given store and week AND the product is 4, 5, 6

0 otherwise

I suggest

```
gen byte wanted1 = 1

foreach p in 4 5 6 {
    bysort store week : egen byte work = max(product == `p')
    replace wanted1 = wanted1 * work
    drop work
}

replace wanted1 = wanted1 * inlist(product, 4, 5, 6)
```

So, the recipe is

- Assume all present. Indicator initialised to 1.
- Change our mind if any is absent. Principles documented at https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/create-variable-recording/ 
  (We just need to multiply by 0 once, and the indicator as a logical product is necessarily zero.)
- Change our mind in respect of other products.

Here's a version without `egen` that should be faster in large datasets:

```
gen byte wanted1 = 1

foreach p in 4 5 6 {
    bysort store week : gen byte work = product == `p'
    bysort store week (work) : replace work = work[_N] 
    replace wanted1 = wanted1 * work
    drop work
}

replace wanted1 = wanted1 * inlist(product, 4, 5, 6)
```

Sorry, I don't understand the definition of `present2`. Occurrences of what precisely?

However, your present code

```
bysort product: generate order = _n
drop tag
bysort product: egen tag=max(order)
```

could be just

```
bysort product : replace tag = _N
```